# How do you say ‘navel orange’ in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

The term ‘[navel orange](http://www.cross-reference-kingdom.com/temo-navel-orange.html)’ appears neither in Benson, nor in Wells, nor in Vikivortaro. The English-language version of Wikipedia treats this term in its article on the orange, and there is an offering in the sidebar for the Esperanto-language version, but the Esperanto-language version is merely a stub, and does not deal with this term. Nor is this term in ReVo, nor in Sonja’s English-Esperanto dictionary. So, would the Esperanto translation of “navel orange” simply be “umbilika oranĝo”? – or is there some niftier rendering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked up the translations in some European languages:

- French: *navel* (f) or *orange Navel* (f)
- German: *Navel* (f) or *Navelorange* (f)
- Spanish: *naranja navel* (f) or *naranja california* (f)
- Italian: *arancio ombelicato* (m)

As you can see, most don't translate *navel*, but instead treat it as a proper noun. It was difficult to find translations for other languages, but I expect there is a similar pattern. It seems that the navel orange is not well-known globally. So I think that you can use either of these:

- ***umbilika oranĝo*** is a valid translation; however
- **navel-*oranĝo*** may be easier for a reader to look up and find information about.

Comment: I’m going to go with “navel-oranĝo”. I’ve added your answer, with attribution, and link, to my online dictionary, here: http://www.cross-reference-kingdom.com/temo-navel-orange.html